# Angular 2 Template parse errors when using ngFor inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

Why Angular 2 doesn't let me create set of child views inside div-block using *ngFor?

The case:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ChoiceComponent} from './choice.component';
import {Question} from './model/Question';

@Component({
    selector: 'question',
    template: `
    <div class="panel">
    {{question.text}}
    <choice *ngFor="let choice of question.choices" [choice]="choice">
    </div>
    `,
    directives: [ChoiceComponent]
})
export class QuestionComponent {

    @Input()
    question: Question; // Input binding from category component ngFor
}
```

causes

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div" ("
    <div class="panel">
    <choice *ngFor="let choice of question.choices" [choice]="choice">
    [ERROR ->]</div>
    "): QuestionComponent@3:4
```

However following works fine, but I want to have question and choice buttons inside a same panel.

```
<div class="panel">
  {{question.text}}
</div>
<choice *ngFor="let choice of question.choices" [choice]="choice">
```

Answer (score 4):

Parser *expects* `<choice>` tag to be closed first until `<div>`.

Try following

```
<div class="panel">
  {{question.text}}
  <choice *ngFor="let choice of question.choices" [choice]="choice">
  </choice>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :-

```
<div class="panel" *ngFor="let choice of question?.choices">
 {{question.text}}
 <choice [choice]="choice"> </choice>
</div>
```

By doing so you are repeating div block and for each repeat there is one text and button. if something unclear yet please ask me or post plunker if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to Close with `</choice>`